# Spring cloud stream producer retries and error handling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have set a spring cloud stream kafka producer and consumer and there are 3 kafka brokers running . I have set `min.insync.replicas` to 4 to see how producer error handling works . The `messagechannel.send` call returns immediately and the producer logs keep saying `NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS` which is fine and expected .

```
server.port: 9050
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        errorChannel:
          destination: error-topic
        output:
          destination: stream-topic
          group: top-group
          producer:
            errorChannelEnabled: true
      kafka:
        bindings:
          output:
            producer:
              retries: 3
              sync: false
        binder:
          autoCreateTopics: true
          configuration:
            value:
              serializer: com.example.kafkapublisher.MySerializer
          producer-properties:
            acks: all
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.errorChannel.consumer.enableDlq: true
```

The above is my producer configuration . Although retries is set to 3 , the producer keeps on retrying a large number of times . Although sync is set to true , the send call comes out immediately . Although error channel and destination is defined , and `errorChannelEnabled` is set to true i do't see the failed message in the error topic `my-error`, neither is the error topic created . Request your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary Kafka producer properties go in the `...producer.configuration` property.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties

> **configuration**

> Map with a key/value pair containing generic Kafka producer properties. The bootstrap.servers property cannot be set here; use multi-binder support if you need to connect to multiple clusters.

> Default: Empty map.

Comment: Thanks Gary . With the updated config (question edited) am able to get the sync flag working . Also the errors raised during producer.send like NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS are being sent to the errorChannel and i am recieing callbacks on the ServiceActivator. However is there a way to send errors arising from producer.send calls like the above , to be sent to a dlq . I have a consumer which is working well and errors thrown by the consumer are correctly moved to a DLQ . The given configuration is for the  producer, though i've given a dlq for the error channel,i dont see it in the error-topic

Comment: No; use a `KafkaTemplate` in the `@ServiceActivator` to send it.

Comment: Thanks . Problem now is am simulating NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS and hence cant route the error to a topic . Is there any other way we can simulate producer errors with the kafka broker being up .I tried with a custom serializer which is blindly throwing an error , however the ServiceActivator is not being invoked in this case

Comment: Also could you please explain what's the behaviour when we set acks = all and sync = true together . If acks = all and sync = false , then the send call will return immediately , is that correct ? then what's the purpose of acks = all . If acks = 0 and sync = true what does that indicate

Comment: See the documentation for what acks=0 means https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_acks `sync=true` means the exception will be thrown while sending, false means the error is sent to the error channel. To cause an error on just one topic, you could reduce its `max.message.bytes` and send a larger record. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_max.message.bytes

Comment: would sync = true ensure  the writes are propagated to all the insync replicas ? i do know about acks , but getting confused with both these configs used together . I presume sync = true is just for getting an exception if at all the leader write is unsuccessful , Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: `sync=true` simply tells Spring to wait for the send result before returning to the sender. It is independent of the acks - all of that is handled by Kafka itself. In practice yes, it means the record is secured in required number of replicas. But it will be much slower than sync=false, for that reason.

Comment: Its quite easy to handle errors with sync=true especially when you want to combine db writes and kafka send msg operations in a single transaction . Otherwise we need to rely on outbox patterns with debezium / eventuate etc which are harder to implement and manage . Any thoughts on to what extent does the performance degrade with sync = true , for my testing on a topic with less than 3 records , send method returned in few milliseconds and it was a 3 node kafka cluster locally on my laptop

Comment: It's definitely easier to code; performance is only really a problem if you want to publish many records in a short time.

Comment: Means if i publish at a high speed on Topic A and a low publish rate on Topic B , only Topic A performance would get affected compared to Topic B , with sync = true . Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes; it is correct - the sync property is per binding.

Comment: Thank you , Any idea why the serialization error was not being caught in `@ServiceActivator` when sync was set to false . Although i didnt try with sync=true which i presume would be thrown back in the same caller thread which invoked send. Also would be great to know if there are other ways to simulate producer errors

Comment: Serialization is always done on the calling thread; the `sync` only relates to whether or not to wait for the async confirmation or not (on the calling thread).

Comment: ok , so regardless of sync , the serialization error would always be sent back to the calling thread , Is that right ? Also would be great to know if there are other ways to simulate producer errors other than `not_enough_replicas` and `max.message.bytes`

Comment: I have not explored other possible ways to simulate errors. You could probably do it with a mock producer, but that would require using a bit of reflection. If you need help with that, I suggest you ask a new question; the admins here don't like long commentary.